# Error while accessing JPA inside Spring Boot Security Authentication

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, spring-security

I'm implementing an API REST with Spring Boot, following some tutorials on the Internet, everything fine until I need to use a refresh token to recover the auth token once it is expired. So in my Spring Boot Security, I added a RefreshToken instance with the ID of the user.

```
@Override
protected void successfulAuthentication(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain,
                                        Authentication auth) throws IOException, ServletException {

    String token = Jwts.builder().setIssuedAt(new Date()).setIssuer(ISSUER_INFO)
            .setSubject(((org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User) auth.getPrincipal()).getUsername())
            .setExpiration(new Date(System.currentTimeMillis() + TOKEN_EXPIRATION_TIME))
            .signWith(SignatureAlgorithm.HS512, SUPER_SECRET_KEY).compact();

    String refreshTokenString = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    RefreshToken refreshToken = new RefreshToken(refreshTokenString, Long.parseLong(StringUtils.substringAfter(((org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User) auth.getPrincipal()).getUsername(), Constants.STRING_SEPARATOR4)));
    refreshTokenRepository.save(refreshToken);   <-------------------------------------- ERROR HERE!!!!

    response.addHeader(HEADER_AUTHORIZACION_KEY, TOKEN_BEARER_PREFIX + " " + token);

    response.addHeader("refreshToken", refreshTokenString);

    response.addHeader("emailHash",
            StringUtils.substringBetween(((org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User) auth.getPrincipal()).getUsername(), Constants.STRING_SEPARATOR1, Constants.STRING_SEPARATOR2)
    );
    response.addHeader("instanceId",
            StringUtils.substringBetween(((org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User) auth.getPrincipal()).getUsername(), Constants.STRING_SEPARATOR2, Constants.STRING_SEPARATOR3)
    );
    response.addHeader("enabled",
            StringUtils.substringBetween(((org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User) auth.getPrincipal()).getUsername(), Constants.STRING_SEPARATOR3, Constants.STRING_SEPARATOR4)
    );
}
```

The error I always get is in the line of .save() of the repository.

```
2020-11-19T17:19:09.613116+00:00 app[web.1]: 2020-11-19 17:19:09.612 ERROR 4 --- [io-56866-exec-4] o.s.b.w.servlet.support.ErrorPageFilter  : Forwarding to error page from request [/login] due to exception [null]
2020-11-19T17:19:09.613127+00:00 app[web.1]:
2020-11-19T17:19:09.613127+00:00 app[web.1]: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
```

I tried before to get a complete user instance from JPA and get the same error when executed findByEmail that I use all over the application without any problem, so I think is something related to persistence, but I'm lost, without that .save(), everything else is working fine, except that the refresh token is not stored :(

Comment: To me it seems like a Bean injection problem. How do you instantiate the repository here? And also, how do you instantiate the SecurityConfig itself? If you use Autowiring, make sure to use it consistently.

Comment: Waw, that's true... solved! I post the answer...thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution! The problem was in the instance of the repository, I did it in the filter using:

```
@Autowired
private RefreshTokenRepository refreshTokenRepository;
```

I don't understand why, but i don't work this way, so I moved the instance in the Security Configuration class, and pass the repository var as a parameter to the filter, then it worked! Thanks k-wasilewski.

If anyone know why the instance with @Autowired in the filter doesn't work, would be nice to know.